# Data Exchange between Applications in a Microservice Achitecture using Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, microservices, lumen, jwt

i'm trying to achieve this using **Lumen / Laravel framework** as my underlying technologies, and also using **JWT Authentication** for the REST APIs. The functionality goes as follows -

1. The **Client Application (Web/Mobile)** is served from one server, houses the front end application that does all the web-API requests
2. The **Auth-Service is on server(A)**, This service(application) houses the Users Table, which is used to login the user, role-management, user registration, log reports and also track all authentication/Administration issues.
3. The **UserData service on server(B)**, this houses the profile table, bio-data information of every registered user from the Server A, via a foreign key (user_id) or otherwise for data relation
4. The **Products Service on Server(C)**, handles all product related issues, customers, orders, categories - on different tables with a foreign key reference to the user on server A.
5. The **Blog Application on Server(D)**, this service manages the user blog posts, blog comments and all blog related issues per user - either using their foreign key(user_id)

**The Problem**

- Login/Logout is done once, and The user has access to every service
- How do i relate the tables on server A to Server B using a foreign Key to manipulate data, and via API calls
- i am using JWT Authentication, How can i launch an application on a different server and still retain the login session, and save data using the login information from a different service on another service. i logged in on server A, i launched the Blog on server D, Server D, read my login information and how do i pull user posts/comments - as though it was a one-to-many relationship or many-to-many relationship model system.
- Since the User Logged in from Server A, do i repeat the same login tables in the other servers so that when ever i launch the applications the data is related and i can run queries on related models remember each application is a different lumen/laravel installation. i'm wondering how i can talk to each application without repeating a process from one server on another server, also recall, that i would have to pull the bio-information from server B, during all these process.

How do i achieve all these. This would have been very easy using the waterfall approach, since there would be just one user table and a user has different relationships, but i'm trying to seperate concerns and build otherwise, but now i'm stuck on how to go about it.

also if there's a preferred alternate technique/method, i would be glad to know. thanks.

Please, refer to the diagram below

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a microservices architecture? It seems like you really want a monolith. Additionally you currently split up your services based on what data it contains, not what your problem domain describes. E.g. a blog post will know a name about an author, but does not care about any products that user has bought. Equally a product service does not care what blogs a user has written.

Comment: i just used a simple system to describe this, just for my audience like you to understand, obviously this could be achieved using a monolith architecture, but its more complex than this..

Comment: any heads up @AndeCaleb ?

Comment: any heads up @AndeCaleb ?

Comment: @stevebaros, yea.. i achieved it.. and its been a while since then.. and i left that project.